# Android virtual Device is offline

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I installed the Android SDK and wrote a application and Built the AVD Manager to see my app on device but when I try to run the project as Android Application , I can't find my device (Target is offline).

Comment: First Restart the avd manager and then run your project as android application. Might this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following things in such scenario

1. Reconnect the device, if its a device.
2. Restart ADB from DDMS prespective.
3. Restart Eclipse or ADT.
4. Restart Device/ Emulator.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The device state is `offline` when you do not accept the fingerprint of your computer in device. Follow these steps to resolve this:
1. Disconnect and connect device
2. You will get a dialogue asking to accept the fingerprint
3, Accept the confirmation
4. If step #3 doesn't work, restart eclipse